# When you touch a banner in iOS app

Tags: ios, iad

is there any code to say something like: the banner has been touched /pressed?

banner.touched doesn't exist, but it is just an example of what could be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to assist you better, you will need to provide just a little more info. Which class is this "banner"? When you say "touched", do you mean when your finger is actively touching the banner, or an event that is fired after you remove your finger having had touched the banner.

Comment: It's about an IAD banner and when I say touched I mean just to click or tap once with your finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The banner view's delegate method `bannerViewActionShouldBegin(_:willLeaveApplication:)` is called "when the user taps the banner view". See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:).

Comment: Then if I want that my app remains in pause while the user is looking at the advertisement (the user has already "touched" the banner) how can I do that?